# How to config logstash to listening on multiple tcp port?

Tags: java, tcp, logstash

I use logstash to collect logs from other component in my project. The log was divided into two type, app_log and sys_log, app_log was sent to tcp port 5000 and sys_log was sent to 5001.
The following is my logstash input config:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    type => app_log
  }
  tcp {
    port => 5001
    type => sys_log
  }
}
```

After I started the logstash, the port 5000 and 5001 are both activated.
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      7650/java
tcp6       0      0 :::5001                 :::*                    LISTEN      7650/java

But I could only receive log from port 5000 normally.when sending log to port 5001, the log was not collected, Is there anything I configured wrongly?

Comment: I have two lumberjack inputs running on separate ports, and it's fine.  Add an output{ stdout {} } stanza to help you debug.

Comment: Good, I will try your advice, thank you!